# How to Replace Text while Maintaining Capitalization?

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

Say I wanted to a string replace on a file with the following contents

```
name
nAmE
naMEbb
NAME
```

And wanted to replace the word "name" with "dave", but keeping the capitalization of the original text.  For example, my desired output would be,

```
dave
dAvE
daVEbb
DAVE
```

Are there any one-liners to do this (preferably in Perl so I can do an in-place substitution across many files)?

**EDIT** 
The problem is ambiguous unless both strings have exactly the same length.  Let's assume it does.

Comment: Original and sustituted string are the same length? Otherwise the definition of "same case" is ambiguous

Answer (score 8):

There are some solutions on perlFaq: 
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS?

One of solutions presented there allows to perform the substitution in a single line, by defining a subroutine (preserve_case):

```
   $string = "this is a TEsT case";
   $string =~ s/(test)/preserve_case($1, "success")/egi;
   print "$string\n";
```

This prints: this is a SUcCESS case

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy but it works:

```
perl -e 'use List::MoreUtils "pairwise"; $_ = "toto naME nAmE"; s/(name)/@x = map(ord, split "", "DAVE"); @y = map(ord>=97?32:0, split "", $1); @c = map chr, pairwise { $a + $b } @x, @y; $" = ""; "@c";/gei; print "$_\n";'
```

one line solution!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether the example from perlfaq works for non-ASCII. 
A variant that doesn't use the XOR hack could be:

```
$text =~ s{$str_to_replace}{my $i=0;join "",map {substr($&,$i++,1)=~/\p{IsLower}/?lc:uc} split //,$str_to_substitute}ieg;
```

But this only works if the `/i` modifier is locale-enabled (see perllocale).